# What is the next number in sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

Consider the following sequence:

> 6211, 4214, 6321, 4135, 6359

What is the next number in that sequence?
What are the rules of that sequence?

I hope you'll enjoy my first question :)

#### EDIT 1:

Sorry guys, with those numbers, it is impossible to find the next one. So I have added the next one so it becomes possible.

The new sequence is:

> 6211, 4214, 6321, 4135, 6359, 4182

#### EDIT 2:

Here is a hint:

> Some numbers where chosen to confuse you. You shouldn't focus on them, but focus on the whole.

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be 6359 and not 6350?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be 6359 and not 6459?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The seventh number is **6136**.

The last digit of each number is the $n$th digit after the decimal point of $\pi$.

The first three digit numbers follow this pattern:

- Place the $n$th Fibonacci number so that the ones' digit is the third digit of the number.
- Then, insert digits so that the sum of the digits of the sum of the digits of the number is equal to to $n$. If the $n$th Fibonacci number is less than 10, then use a sequence alternating $6$ and $4$ to fill in the first digit, and then fill in the second digit as appropriate.

So the eleven terms of the sequence would be:

> 6211, 4214, 6321, 4135, 6359, 4182, 6136, 9215, 8343, 4555, 4898

The sequence ends there since the next Fibonacci number is 144 which would no longer ensure the sum-of-digits rule to be intact.

Comment: Argh, beat me to it.

Comment: Your solution pinning $4$ as the second digit seems a bit iffy.

Comment: If you look at the update I've made, you'll see you're on the right tracks :)

Comment: You have all the information you need to solve it. There is no unknown sequence of number involved.

Comment: The fact the all the 2nd numbers are $\le 4$ makes me think the 2nd number might be self-referential in some way.

Comment: Oh, so it was what I was thinking of earlier, then.

Comment: I added a hint to help you

Comment: You have the right number but not the right explanation. Your rules wont work with the next number.

Comment: The next number should be 4616, then?

Comment: That's not it and it's pretty off. But you are really close in the rules you have.

Comment: Shoot, I thought I had it. In any case it fits the given numbers and seems elegant enough... what did you intend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23031/discussion-between-a-d-and-joe-z).